# megacli: Failed to alloc kernel SGL buffer for IOCTL

Tags: debian, raid, megaraid, megacli

Today one of my servers started sending me alerts about non-optimal RAID state. These were triggered by a very simple script run by cron -- if it detects that not all of the disks report 'Optimal' state, it sends an alert.

Now, the issue is that the RAID seems to be fine but the `megacli -LDInfo -Lall -aALL` command invoked by the script fails repeatedly leaving a cryptic error message in syslog:
`megacli: Failed to alloc kernel SGL buffer for IOCTL`. The curious thing is that the command does work sometimes and does return output, but most of the time it just returns two blank lines and the exit code:

```
# megacli -LDInfo -Lall -aALL


Exit Code: 0x00
```

The same goes for `megacli` with other parameters like `megacli -AdpAllInfo -aAll`. Every time the command fails the said error appears in syslog.

This has never happened before, as far as I can remember. No changes were made at the server recently. The adapter is a `PERC 6/i Integrated` and the server runs under Debian Wheezy.

What could possibly be the issue and where do I start resolving this?

EDIT:

```
# megacli -v


      MegaCLI SAS RAID Management Tool  Ver 5.00.12 May 08, 2009

    (c)Copyright 2009, LSI Corporation, All Rights Reserved.

Exit Code: 0x00
```

At least this command works every time without triggering the error ;) I've just realised this is an old release of megacli. Still, it shouldn't matter since the very same setup has been working a couple dozen of months with no problem and now suddenly decided to go wild.

Comment: It probably _does_ matter. Servers are not static despite our best efforts. I'd update that first.

Comment: After reviewing the case with a colleague we deduced it must have been some memory corruption and decided to reboot the server. Is been working fine since then, a week already. Yeah, I know a reboot is not really a solution but hey, it helped as a last resort.

Comment: This has happened to me again, on a different server, after some 700 days of uptime (yes, shame on me for that). Same symptoms, same errors in syslog, same solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a debian bug report for this issue, see:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=703356

There doesn't seem to be a fix as of now, and it also happens with recent kernels. My personal suspect is Xen. Do you run Xen on this host?

Comment: Well, yes, your suspicion is correct, both my hosts (from the OP and the comment to that) are running Xen.